# Cannot Insert into Table with Foreign Key Prisma

Tags: node.js, prisma

I am trying to learn Prisma by building a Node.js app. I am now trying to insert into the `recipe` table that has the foreign key for the `user` table using the following query:

```
const response = await prisma.recipe.create({
  data: {
    name,
    description,
    ingredients,
    likes,
    downloads,
    user: {
      connect: [{ id: user_id }],
    },
  }
});
```

But this seems to fail every time. I read the documentation and I got the above piece of code from there, but it still isn't working. What am I doing wrong, please help. This is my schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model comments {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_id   Int
  recipe_id Int
  likes     BigInt
  comment   String    @db.Text
  user      user      @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "comments_ibfk_1")
  recipe    recipe    @relation(fields: [recipe_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "comments_ibfk_2")
  replies   replies[]

  @@index([recipe_id], map: "recipe_id")
  @@index([user_id], map: "user_id")
}

model recipe {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_id     Int
  name        String     @db.Text
  description String     @db.Text
  ingredients String     @db.Text
  likes       BigInt
  downloads   BigInt
  created_at  DateTime   @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime
  deleted_at  DateTime   @db.DateTime(0)
  comments    comments[]
  user        user       @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "recipe_ibfk_1")

  @@index([user_id], map: "user_id")
}

model replies {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  comment_id Int
  reply      String   @db.Text
  comments   comments @relation(fields: [comment_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "replies_ibfk_1")

  @@index([comment_id], map: "comment_id")
}

model user {
  id       Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String     @db.Text
  email    String     @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(50)
  password String     @db.Text
  phone    String     @db.Text
  age      Int
  location String     @db.Text
  image    String     @db.Text
  comments comments[]
  recipe   recipe[]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your schema as well?

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was with JSON not being able to Stringify BigInt, This issue was discussed and solved [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-953187833). The solution is to add `BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function () { return this.toString() };` to your root server file in node.js. It'll start working.